# How to Get GA to do Site Search with Tumblr

Tags: google-analytics, tumblr

In Tumblr, searches are set up so that the query is a method/parameter of the search controller. Basically it looks like this: `/search/:query`.

I've been playing around from the client side trying to edit it so that it posts in this format:

```
/search/example?q=example
```

I'm doing this because GA looks for a parameter in searches. My problem is is that from the JavaScript to the form methods and actions, I cannot get the thing to spit out a query parameter at the end.

Is there anyway to tell Google to look for `/search/:query` instead of looking for a parameter in the URI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by creating an advanced filter.

Go to your account **Admin** and then either click on the **Account > All filters** button on the left, or else the **View > Filters** button the right.  Which one you use depends on whether you want this to be applied to all properties/views of the account, or only to an individual view.

Then, click the **+ New Filter** button.

Enter in a name for your **Filter Name** such as "search string"

For filter type, select **Custom filter** radio button.

Then select the **Advanced** radio button.

Then from the **Field A->Extract A** dropdown, select `Request URI`.  In the input field to the right of this, enter in `^\/search\/(.*)`

Then from the **Output To->Construtor** dropdown, select `Search Term`. In the input field to the right of this, enter in `$A1`

Then save the filter and you should be good to go.

Comment: @BenMorganIO It's GA's syntax for specifying regex capture groups (the stuff between parens). `$A` refers to `Field A` and `1` refers to the capture group #. `$A0` will refer to the match as a whole, and `$A1` the `(.*)` match, `$A2` would be the 2nd (but there isn't one for this), etc..

Comment: so if your url is "/search/foobar", `$A0` would have value "/search/foobar" and `$A1` will have value "foobar"

Comment: Ah. Should I use `\?q=$A1` for the constructor?

Comment: I've got the filter saved on my view. I've also deactivated my GA blocker and I'm seeing me in real time now. I supply a search term and its not converting it.

Comment: if your actual url is `/search/searchterm` then you should do as I show.  Alternatively you *could* just do a search and replace instead of advanced filter, and set `q` to be your search term param in the search settings.

Comment: @BenMorganIO But in any case, real time data only shows the basic pageview stuff. You will need to wait a few hours to see search term data show up